# Using array.filter down multiple levels

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a filter function, which uses `filter` to quickly search a text in an array:

```
filtered = filtered.filter((row) => {
   return Object.keys(row).some((key) => {
        return String(row[key]).toLowerCase().indexOf(this.quickSearch.toLowerCase()) > -1
      })
   })
```

This works great for single level array, but not sure how to adapt it to work down unknown number of levels of array of objects like this

```
{
   'name': 'james',
   'post': {
        'name': 'my favorite teams'
    }
}
```

The code above finds `james`, no problem, but it will not find `teams` as its not going deep enough.

Naturally I don't want to hardcode something like `if row[key] == 'post'`, because I'm using this code for multiple data sources and need it to be dynamic.

How do I adapt this to work in multi level arrays like the example above?

Comment: I don't understand how that code would work with the example input you provided. The example you've shown is an object, not an array. The filter method can only be used on arrays.

Comment: sorry the example object above is within the array

Comment: Is there only one level down (like the example) or there could be more?

Comment: one level of array, but multiple objects within objects - sorry I mislabelled the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there are many levels, then recursion is the best solution:

```
let searchString = this.quickSearch.toLowerCase();                       // do this only once instead of calling toLowerCase over and over again, besides we are using a regular function (not an arrow one) so "this" will be messed up anyways
filtered = filtered.filter(function search(row) {                        // name the function so we can use recursion (thus we can't use an arrow function)
   return Object.keys(row).some((key) => {                               // ...
       if(typeof row[key] === "string") {                                // if the current property is a string
           return row[key].toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString) > -1;     // then check if it contains the search string
       } else if(row[key] && typeof row[key] === "object") {             // oterwise, if it's an object
           return search(row[key]);                                      // do a recursive check
       }
       return false;                                                     // return false for any other type (not really necessary as undefined will be returned implicitly)
   });
});
```

Comment: just like magic! exactly what I was after with explanations too! thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could use a recursive function that calls itself on the values of objects and arrays (using [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) and [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)):

```js
const containsDeep = (text) => (value) => {
  if(!value) return false;
  const valueType = typeof value;
  
  if(valueType === 'string') {
    return value.toLowerCase().indexOf(text.toLowerCase()) > -1;
  }
  if(Array.isArray(value)) {
    return value.some(containsDeep(text));
  }
  if(valueType === 'object') {
    return Object.values(value).some(containsDeep(text));
  }
  return false;
};

const data = [
  {
   'name': 'bar',
   'post': {
      'name': 'my favorite teams'
    }
  },
  {
    'name': 'fizz',
    'posts': [{'name': 'buzz'}]
  },
  {
    'name': 'bla',
    'post': {
      'name': 'blee',
      'comments': [null, {'name': 'bar'}]
    }
  },
  {
   'name': 'foo',
   'post': {
      'name': 'bar'
    }
  }
];

const result = data.filter(containsDeep('bar'));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: `typeof null === "object"`.

Comment: `if(!value) return false;` I specifically added a case where `null` is encountered (third element of `data`).

Comment: Ah! I didn't see that.