# Mutilevel array filter for search implementation

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to implement search with multilevel array.

Consider i have JSON multilevel array as below

```
const testData = [
        {
            menu: 'Test',
            submenu: [
                {
                    menu: 'Test1',
                },
                {
                    menu: 'Test2',
                    submenu: [
                        {
                            menu: 'Test2.1',
                        },
                        {
                            menu: 'Test2.2',
                        },
                        {
                            menu: 'Test2.3',
                        },
                    ],
                },
            {
        menu: 'TestNew',
        submenu: [
            {
                menu: 'TestNew1.1',
            },
            {
                menu: 'TestNew1.2'
            },
            {
                menu: 'TestNew1.3',
            },
        ],
    },
            ],
        }]
```

i have search box if i try to search for a word Test2.3 i would like the JSON to be in below format

```
const testData = [
        {
            menu: 'Test',
            submenu: [

                {
                    menu: 'Test2',
                    submenu: [
                        {
                            menu: 'Test2.3'
                        },
                    ],
                },
            ],
        }]
```

I have referenced the link [Using array.filter down multiple levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47823734/using-array-filter-down-multiple-levels) but it doesn't meet my output. its returning all the submenu like below

```
const testData = [
        {
            menu: 'Test',
            submenu: [
                {
                    menu: 'Test1',
                },
                {
                    menu: 'Test2',
                    submenu: [
                        {
                            menu: 'Test2.1',
                        },
                        {
                            menu: 'Test2.2',
                        },
                        {
                            menu: 'Test2.3',
                        },
                    ],
                },
            ],
        }]
```

Do we have any another method to meet my expectations.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a recursive approach with `reduce` method that will only return those sub menu elements where the target value is found and filter out the other elements.

```js
const data = [{"menu":"Test","submenu":[{"menu":"Test1"},{"menu":"Test2","submenu":[{"menu":"Test2.1"},{"menu":"Test2.2"},{"menu":"Test2.3"}]},{"menu":"TestNew","submenu":[{"menu":"TestNew1.1"},{"menu":"TestNew1.2"},{"menu":"TestNew1.3"}]}]}]

function search(data, value) {
  return data.reduce((r, e) => {
    const object = { ...e }
    const result = search(e.submenu || [], value)
    if (result.length) object.submenu = result
    if (e.menu == value || result.length) r.push(object)
    return r;
  }, [])
}

console.log(search(data, 'Test2.1'))
console.log(search(data, 'TestNew1.3'))
```

Comment: I'm glad I could help.